# Duvida/problema ao redirecionar após envio de formulário com o node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize-js

Bom, sou novato na programação e estou tentando fazer um protótipo de registro de frequencia para aprender um pouco mais como manusear o banco de dados. A minha aplicação conta com uma área que eu consigo estar visualizando todos os posts e adicionando mais caso preciso (pode estar visualizando todos os alunos), usei algumas logicas para estar criando salas e assim exibindo apenas os alunos que estão nas salas, ou seja, um filtro para que cada aluno apareça somente em sua sala. Vamos ao meu problema, para que isso fosse possível eu realizei algumas logicas onde basicamente eu pegava a URL da pagina gerada e incluía no filtro, assim exibia apenas aqueles alunos de determinada sala (ainda não consegui estar realizando o relacionamento/associação de tabelas). Com isso, como o método de inserir o post é o mesmo, utilizei o mesmo código de app.post para estar incluindo os dados na tabela quanto na parte onde mostrava tudo e quanto na parte onde mostrava com filtros, onde basicamente não consigo estar redirecionando para a mesma pagina de formulário, pois podem apresentar ser a mesma página mas com os filtros estou mostrando nas opções apenas os alunos da sala.

Essa imagem abaixo mostra o formulário sem filtro, ou seja, pode ser incluso a presença para o aluno em qualquer sala (presença = post) (URL: http://localhost:8081/cad?)

[image]

Já a essa outra imagem mostra o formulário com o filtro, como pode observar o aluno é da sala dois e só pode ser incluso na sala dois. (URL: http://localhost:8081/postpro/sala2?)

[image]

Com isso vem o problema, pois ao acionar o post:

```
 app.post('/addPost', function(req, res){
        Post.create({
            titulo: req.body.titulo, //seria o horário
            conteudo: req.body.conteudo, // seria o nome do aluno
            sala: req.body.sala
        }).then(function(){
            res.redirect()
        }).catch(function(erro){
            res.send("Houve um erro: "+erro)
        })
    })
```

ele está sendo redirecionado para uma unica pagina, mas também não consigo (caso for possível, me desculpem) estar pegando a url da pagina com filtro, pois ela foi formada com alguns req.params, assim toda vez que eu envio o fomulário sou redirecionado para uma pagina, mas eu queria saber se é possível após estar enviando o formulário eu estar permanecendo na mesma pagina.

Obs: eu estou utilizando o Mysql, sequelize, node.js, handlebars e alguns javascripts para isso.

Retirei o res.redirect() mas a pagina fica apenas carregando, isso seria uma solução para agora, mas fica algo estranho de se ver, teria como estar arrumando ou colocando de outra forma?

Comment: Cara ficou bem confuso sua pergunta, realmente não compreendi, mas, pelo que li está tendo problemas para pegar os parâmetros da url. Pra ir começando a te dar uma luz, pode pegar os parâmetros com **req.params**

Comment: sim, eu estou realizando isso, utilizo o params para filtrar os dados, após isso estou usando mesmo app.post para adicionar postagens, mas  ao adicionar é redirecionado para outra pagina, sendo que são duas paginas diferentes, apenas queria saber se tem como não ser redirecionado pra nenhuma pagina, ou seja, manter na pagina de formulario que está no momento.